# How to check the word document is already opened or not.?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, ms-office

In my application,i am creating the word document using vb.net.if i close the application and running again and open the same document..but the document is already opened,how to check the word document is already opened or not..?

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
  Dim p() As Process = Process.GetProcessesByName("WinWord")

    If p.Count = 0 Then

       ' No word instance opened

    Else

       ' Any Word instance opened

  End If
```